# C# - Return true if all comparisons are true

Tags: c#

I have a `queue[i]` for each `drone[i]`.

**MY QUESTION:** How can make a code that waits for each `drone[i].actual_position == drone[i].desired_position` instead of my current code that only waits if the current drone `drone[i]desired_position == drone[i].actual_position`

So instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drones.Length; i++)
{
    queue[i].Enqueue(drone[i].desired_position);

    if (drone[i]desired_position == drone[i].actual_position) 
    {
        queue[i].Dequeue();
        queue[i].Enqueue(next_desired_position);
    } 
}
```

I want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drones.Length; i++)
{
    queue[i].Enqueue(drone[i].desired_position);

    //TODO: what should I put into "if"?
    if (/* all drone[i]desired_position == drone[i].actual_position */) 
    {
        queue[i].Dequeue();
        queue[i].Enqueue(next_desired_position)
    } 
}
```

TLDR: I want to make sure every drone is in his desired position before dequeue and go to the next position so the drones are syncronized.

Comment: Are you looking for *Linq*? `drone.All(d => d.desired_position == d.actual_position)`

Comment: it can be. But the structure of my code is correct? can it be inside the for loop?

Comment: Drone collection is fixed or there are updates during the for cycle?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're looking for an `All` *Linq* command as well as `for` loop and `if` *swapped*:

```
 // If all drones are at their expected positions
 if (drone.All(d => d.desired_position == d.actual_position))
   // then set new goals for each drone:
   for (int i = 0; i < drone.Length; ++i) {
     // remove the target achieved
     queue[i].Dequeue();
     // but add a new location to go
     queue[i].Enqueue(next_desired_position) 
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you´re lookging for is Linq´s [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx)-method:

```
var allOkay = drones.All(d => d.desired_position == d.actual_position);
if(allOkay) 
{
    foreach(var drone in drones) 
        drone.Dequeue();
}
```